# Semantic UI - Change Theme

Tags: semantic-ui

I can't get the theme selection to work in Semantic UI.

I attempt to follow the instructions provided in the [workflow section](http://learnsemantic.com/guide/expert.html#manual-install) of the documentation:

> Files in the `examples/` folder of your project can be useful for testing out changes in  your UI. For example, you might run gulp watch download a new theme to `src/site/themes/` then adjust your `theme.config` file with the name of the new theme and refresh `examples/kitchensink.html` to inspect changes in the theme.

So in the semantic ui directory, after the suitable gulp build / gulp install steps,

1. I type `gulp watch`,
2. I modify `src/theme.config`, for example:

   ```
   ...
   /* Elements */
   @button     : 'material';
   ...
   ```
3. The file `dist/semantic.css` is regenerated (says inotify).

So far so good ... except that the rendering of the `examples/kitchensink` is still the default one.
A closer look at `dist/semantic.css` shows that it is actually identical to the original one.

Could anyone point out the (probably obvious) issue in my process ?

Answer (score 19):

**Step 1.** Change `/src/themes/theme.config` to reflect your desired theme (ex. @button: 'material')

**Step 2.** Rebuild - `gulp build`

**Step 3.** Refresh your browser

Comment: I find semantic-ui docs insufficient, I spent a good hour to do this and there is no mention of this in the docs anywhere. (or buried somewhere I missed/couldn't find)

Comment: It works, thank you. Apparently, 'gulp watch' doesn't work as intended (see also <https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1344>).

Comment: Did you get it working? I have followed your instructions but I am still seeing the default theme

Comment: Updating node may work now. At the time of the post, the ```watch``` wasn't working as expected.

Comment: At first it didn't work for me. Then I bring back the default theme folder at src/themes/ (I removed it for some trial and error). Then it worked! Looks like the default theme must be always there, which makes sense as it is the fallback theme. But at least there should be some kind of notification if the default theme is missing.

Comment: Where is the list of availible themes?