# Semantic UI doesn't apply the theme specified in theme.config

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

**What Do I want to achieve?**

I want to add a button in my App.js file. It should be the button from the theme, that I've specified in the theme.config file.

First want to say, that I've read this question from stack overflow already: [Semantic UI - Change Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213694/semantic-ui-change-theme)

I've tried the steps from the answer, but those didn't help me.

And I've read the documentation:
https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html

As far as I understand, I need to change the value which is specified in the theme.config file. This file is located in

**projectFolder/semantic/src/theme.config**

In the theme.config file, there is this global variable @site. I changed this to 'github', ran a gulp build (as written in the SO answer, which is provided at the beginning of the question), and reloaded the dev server. But I still see the default button.

```
/* Global */
@site        : 'github';
@reset       : 'default';
```

I've changed also the value of the button variable to 'github'. But that doesn't work too.

```
/* Elements */
@button      : 'github';
```

**App.js file**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button>Click here</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my **index.js** file I've also imported semantic-ui-css. Is there something else to import?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`semantic-ui-css` npm library only provides the default CSS theme. <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS)</sup>

After running `gulp build`, you need to import the css file in the `dist` folder and not the one from `semantic-ui-css`. At this point, `semantic-ui-css` isn't necessary to be installed in the project since you have `semantic-ui` library which includes the themes <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI#recommended-install)</sup>.

```
import '<install-folder>/dist/semantic.css'
```

**Note that** `<install-folder>` is the folder path relative to the project folder.

Comment: After entering the relative path in the index.js file, I got an error warning, that I can't import paths, which are outside of the src folder. So I moved the semantic folder (which is in the root structure of the project) inside the src folder and ran the gulp build again. I imported the correct semantic.css file, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I figured out that I need to adjust the paths in the semantic.json file located in the root project folder (because I moved the semantic folder from the root project structure inside the src folder). The value of the key "base" inside the json file is now "base": "src/semantic/" instead of semantic/. It works now.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. I had assumed that semantic was installed in the project. :)